# how do you create a pytable inside a folder using openFile?

Tags: python, pytables

I am using Pytables and am wondering how to create an h5 database within a folder.

For example, its easy to create a database file like so:

```
from tables import *
beta = openFile("test2.h5",mode = 'w')
```

this creates a file in the python directory. What if I wanted to create the file test2.h5 within a sub folder? how can you change the directory in which the file is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import tables

path = '/path/to/your/h5_files'
beta = tables.openFile(os.path.join(path, "test2.h5"), mode='w')
```

creates a new file in `/path/to/your/h5_files/test2.h5`